# looping through list of dictionaries python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to access a dictionary within a list and cannot seem to get my for loop to get the key, then the value.

I've placed an image herein so that its easy for me to explain.

[image]

so you can see, I would like to navigate to `currency = AUD` and assign the balance value to a variable, call it `aud_balance`

```
for curr in result_bal_qr:
    for k in curr: 
        if curr[k] == 'AUD':
```

I cannot seem to get the key `AUD`. so I'm officially stuck.

I've tried to search for dictionary inside of lists etc but no examples of my problem, or maybe even understood my problem wrong (highly likely)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You have a list of dicts. You want to iterate over the list as you are doing, but you don't want to iterate over each dict itself; you just want to check its `currency` key. So:

```
for curr in result_bal_qrp:
    if curr['currency'] == 'AUD':
        print(curr['balance'])
```

Note, if you're going to be iterating over this list multiple times to find different currencies, it may be worth converting it to a simple dict of currency to balance:

```
curr_dict = {d['currency']: d['balance'] for d in result_bal_qrp}
```

and now you can do `curr_dict['AUD']` to get the Australian balance.

Comment: incredible how fast some of you get this....incredible... who wants to teach me python?

Comment: I would check first if `curr['currency']` exists or is it implicit with `if curr['currency'] == 'AUD':` ?

Comment: sure, was also thinking what happens if its a null balance?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `list Comprehension`

```
aud_balance = [d['balance'] for d in l if d['currency'] == 'AUD']
```