# how do I get something in this value?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-requests

```
{"Keyword":"roblox","StartIndex":0,"MaxRows":12,"TotalResults":10000,"UserSearchResults":[{"UserId":1,"Name":"ROBLOX","DisplayName":"ROBLOX","Blurb":"Welcome to the Roblox profile! This is where you can check out the newest items in the catalog, and get a jumpstart on exploring and building on our Imagination Platform. If you want news on updates to the Roblox platform, or great new experiences to play with friends, check out blog.roblox.com. Please note, this is an automated account. If you need to reach Roblox for any customer service needs find help at www.roblox.com/help","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/1/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":7504,"Name":"Dragon Roblox","DisplayName":"Dragon Roblox","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/7504/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":5401,"Name":"Alpha Roblox","DisplayName":"Alpha Roblox","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/5401/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":2257,"Name":"roblox alpha test","DisplayName":"roblox alpha test","Blurb":"[ Content Deleted ]","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/2257/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":477673841,"Name":"roblox_new5","DisplayName":"roblox_new5","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/477673841/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":477457467,"Name":"ROBLOX_REDPRO","DisplayName":"ROBLOX_REDPRO","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/477457467/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":476078112,"Name":"robloxbombboy","DisplayName":"robloxbombboy","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/476078112/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":470927030,"Name":"robloxXpertPRo","DisplayName":"robloxXpertPRo","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/470927030/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":474924046,"Name":"ROBLOXF4KE","DisplayName":"ROBLOXF4KE","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/474924046/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":471446101,"Name":"robloxplayer12474","DisplayName":"robloxplayer12474","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/471446101/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":476443526,"Name":"robloxgio2009","DisplayName":"robloxgio2009","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/476443526/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""},{"UserId":476338383,"Name":"Roblox00118","DisplayName":"Roblox00118","Blurb":"","PreviousUserNamesCsv":"","IsOnline":false,"LastLocation":null,"UserProfilePageUrl":"/users/476338383/profile","LastSeenDate":null,"PrimaryGroup":"","PrimaryGroupUrl":""}]}
```

Im sorry if that looks like a mess but I was messing with python requests

```py
s = requests.Session()
search = s.get("https://www.roblox.com/search/users/results?keyword=roblox&maxRows=12&startIndex=0").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(search,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

so when I printed soup it printed that and I have no idea what type of thing it printed, all I want to know is how to access the list inside this array, specifically the first one, the one with the

```
[{'UserId':1, 'Name':"ROBLOX"}]
```

I'm sure this is not a request problem but just some sort of python array problem.

Comment: Looks like you want to know how to parse through the UserSearchResults? Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081291/looping-through-list-of-dictionaries-python

Answer (score 1):

Your data is [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). You can convert it into a python dictionary using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json%20loads#json.loads):

```
import json
users = json.loads(soup)
```

You can then access the first user by:

```
print(users['UserSearchResults'][0])
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
{
 'UserId': 1,
 'Name': 'ROBLOX',
 'DisplayName': 'ROBLOX',
 'Blurb': 'Welcome to the Roblox profile! This is where you can check out the newest items in the catalog, and get a jumpstart on exploring and building on our Imagination Platform. If you want news on updates to the Roblox platform, or great new experiences to play with friends, check out blog.roblox.com. Please note, this is an automated account. If you need to reach Roblox for any customer service needs find help at www.roblox.com/help',
 'PreviousUserNamesCsv': '',
 'IsOnline': False,
 'LastLocation': None,
 'UserProfilePageUrl': '/users/1/profile',
 'LastSeenDate': None,
 'PrimaryGroup': '',
 'PrimaryGroupUrl': ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the response is JSON, you can use the Requests `Response.json()` method to get it parsed:

```
url = "https://www.roblox.com/search/users/results?keyword=roblox&maxRows=12&startIndex=0"
s = requests.Session()
search = s.get(url).json()
print(search["UserSearchResults"][0])
```